# stop threaded STDIN listeners from interfering with each other

Tags: ruby

Here is my main thread, which does nothing but launch other threads and then sleeps forever while the other threads do their work.

```
require 'io/console'
4.times { Thread.new { loop { App.process_char(STDIN.getch) } } }
loop { sleep }
```

This is running for the duration of my program and sends all individual keystrokes to `App.process_char`. However, some inputs will cause this method to run an additional `gets.chomp`. This is not working - it's not getting input because the other threads are eating it all.

I'm thinking there's a way to isolate my STDIN from existing thread listeners before calling gets.chomp. In searched I've seen a mention of redefining `$stdin` and `$stdout` but I'm not sure how to maintain the ability to capture user keystrokes.

Comment: There is insufficient information to answer your question properly. Why do you need multiple threads reading STDIN? Why not just a single thread for input processing. Don't make it harder than it needs to be. Otherwise you will end up with a lot of `Mutex` sections and potentially quickly leads to needlessly complex code.

Comment: @Casper this application reads each individual keystroke and plays a different sound accordingly. It's like a command line drum set. I previously had the input processing happening in the main thread, but it wasn't doing a good job recognizing simultaneous keystrokes. That's why I am using this multithreaded approach. The complicating factor is there are 'special commands' which require additional user input. I.e. when I type `/t=` it prompts me for a tempo, which I normally would type in and press enter.

Comment: This is never going to work. Input and output should be handled by one thread, and one thread *only*. If you need to fan out those keystrokes to different handlers in different threads, do that in a dispatch loop. You might want to use something like [Queue](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Queue.html) to handle inter-thread communication.

Comment: @tadman i guess you're right, it seems `STDIN.getch` captures simultaneous keystrokes just as well in a single thread as in multiple threads. I suppose the limitation is on my keyboard hardware.

Comment: If on Linux/OSX/Unix you might want to look into reading raw scancodes insted of STDIN. That way you will have a more direct view of keyboard states.

Comment: http://www.gcat.org.uk/tech/?p=70

Comment: `getch` is a pretty crappy way to do keyboard input. Casper's right, you probably want to use something more raw, listening for key codes, not characters, though if you're getting really deep into input handling you probably want [Curses](https://github.com/ruby/curses) or something like it, a library built around that sort of thing.